# wpf resize of a usercontrol through thumb is not proportional to dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to resize a custom usercontrol through a thumb positioned inside the usercontrol itself.

This is the usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ER.Entity"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ER"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Name="entityRoot">
<Grid Name="entityGrid">
    <Thumb x:Name="resizeThumb" Height="10" Width="10" Margin="200,90,-15,-10" DragDelta="Resize" />
    <Border  Opacity="100" BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBox1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=entityRoot, Path=EntityName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" PreviewMouseDown="EntityPreviewMouseDownHandler" PreviewMouseMove="EntityPreviewMouseMoveHandler" PreviewMouseUp="EntityPreviewMouseUpHandler" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And this is the method triggered by the DragDelta event:

```
private void Resize(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        entityGrid.SetValue(WidthProperty, entityGrid.ActualWidth + e.HorizontalChange);
        entityGrid.SetValue(HeightProperty, entityGrid.ActualHeight + e.VerticalChange);
    }
```

The problem is that, when i drag the thumb, the resizing of the usercontrol is much bigger than the mouse movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that because your `Thumb` object is referenced to the left and top of the `Grid`, when you change the size of the `Grid` that in turn causes an effective relative movement of the `Thumb` in addition to the movement caused by the mouse.

Changing the `Thumb` alignment to be `Right` and `Bottom`, and moving the `Thumb` positioning from the `Thumb.Margin` to the `Grid`'s `Width` and `Height` properties allows the `Thumb` to resize the `Grid` as intended:

```
<Grid Name="entityGrid" Width="200" Height="90">
  <Thumb x:Name="resizeThumb" Height="10" Width="10"
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Margin="0,0,-15,-10" DragDelta="Resize" />
  <Border  Opacity="100" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBox1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="{Binding ElementName=entityRoot, Path=EntityName}"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               PreviewMouseDown="EntityPreviewMouseDownHandler"
               PreviewMouseMove="EntityPreviewMouseMoveHandler" 
               PreviewMouseUp="EntityPreviewMouseUpHandler" />
  </Border>
</Grid>
```